# React app env file don't recognize docker container reference

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have this docker container that runs backend and front apps in the same network like above.

Backend:

```
gateway-api:
build:
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  context: ./backend/gateway-api-master
image: gateway-api:latest
container_name: gateway-api-docker
networks:
  - energy
depends_on:
  - kafka
ports:
  - 81:80
volumes:
- ./gateway-api:/usr/src/app
- /usr/src/app/node_modules
command: npm run start:prod
logging:
  #driver: none
  options:
    max-size: "10m"
    max-file: "3"
```

Frontend:

```
front-energy:
build:
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  context: ./frontend/front-energy-master            
image: front-energy
container_name: front-energy-docker
networks:
  - energy
depends_on:
  - gateway-api
ports:
  - 3000:3000
logging:
  #driver: none
  options:
    max-size: "10m"
    max-file: "3"
```

The reference to the backend api is in env file ".env"

```
REACT_APP_CRUD = 'http://gateway-api/crud/v1'
```

Here, I call the api using axios

```
const api_auth = axios.create({
   baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_CRUD,
});
```

But when i open the frontend system, this errors appears in the console
[image]

Please, can anyone help with this. I using docker and docker-compose

Thank you all.

Comment: Your application is running in a browser, not in a container, and it can't use Docker networking features.  You need to connect to a published port from your backend, or better, run both parts behind a reverse proxy and use a path-only URL.

Comment: Does ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend) answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

The error you are encountering might be due to the way you are referencing the backend API URL in your frontend code.
Ensure both backend and frontend containers are in the same Docker network, as indicated by the "energy" network in your configuration.

Make sure that the backend API is running and accessible at the specified URL (http://gateway-api) within the Docker network.

Double-check the environment variables in your frontend application. Verify that the ".env" file contains the correct reference to the backend API URL, like this:
REACT_APP_CRUD=http://gateway-api:80/crud/v1

Modify your frontend code to use the correct environment variable:

```js
const api_auth = axios.create({
   baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_CRUD,
});
```

Restart both the backend and frontend containers to apply the changes:

```css
docker-compose up --build
```

After the containers are up and running, open the frontend system in your browser, and the error should be resolved.
Remember to replace any other references to the backend API URL in your frontend code with the appropriate environment variable.

By following these steps, your frontend application should be able to communicate with the backend API without any issues. If you encounter any further problems, double-check the network configurations and ensure both containers are up and running.